# Reliable email delivery method?

Tags: .net, iis, smtp

I'm presently using Google's SMTP servers from my ASP.NET application, via `SmtpClient`. This works fairly well, except that Google's SMTP servers are not *always* reachable:

> SMTP Error (from: ***): System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Using the `SMTP Server` role of `IIS7` it looks like I can have outbound email stored in a *pickup directory*. This sounds great, but what happens after that? Do I need to write an application that deals with those files, or can I get `IIS7` to handle sending them for me?

**edit**: the authentication information was not wrong folks, this error message was just unhelpful; the login information was the same info I've been using for years, and things went back to normal later that day. It was an intermittent outtage, and this was the error message it returned.

Comment: `Authentication Required.`  That means your login was wrong.

Comment: @SLaks It wasn't wrong; it's the same login I've been using for years. It worked again the next day, infact, it only gave that issue for a few hours during that day.

Comment: Note that Google's SMTP servers will refuse to send large volumes of email.  Use a dedicated service like SendGrid or MailGun.

Comment: No server is *always* reachable.

Answer (score 1):

The pickup directory mechanism works with IIS 7's built-in SMTP server.

To use it, you need to run your own SMTP server.
Running an SMTP server is a complicated and involved task; I strongly disrecommend it.

Comment: Care to elaborate a little?

Comment: +1 "I strongly disrecommend it." @Mr.Smith: If you run your own SMTP server, you have to be very careful with security to ensure that people don't start using it as an open relay. Also, you'll need a domain name, the server will need an MX record registered for DNS so that other servers can confirm that you are who you say you are (they often do reverse DNS lookups to prevent spam), etc. Do a little searching about what's involved in running an SMTP server. It's non-trivial. And if you get it going, you too will have trouble with intermittent failures.

Comment: @JimMischel Well, I do own and operate [Pixel Champions](http://www.pixelchampions.com). btw, it looks like Google SMTP servers failed due to a usage limit (500 emails / 24 hours).

Comment: I believe Mr. Smith is right.  This is exactly the error that you will get if you exceed gmail's daily outgoing limit.  Running your own mail server is an option, or you might want to think about using a different SMTP provider that will allow a greater volume of outgoing messages, such as SendGrid or Jango SMTP.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you were able to hit the Google smtp server but you had bad credentials - Authentication Required.

You will need to set up your own SMTP server to get the pickup Directory handled.  A few years ago I set up a Zimbra client that was pretty easy.  Looks like they have gone off the cloud deep end since then but probably still have a lightwieght server.

[Zimbra email server](http://www.zimbra.com/)

Comment: Interesting. So IIS7 won't actually function as an SMTP server, but rather just deliver to either another SMTP server, or to a pick-up directory?

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7-and-above Interesting, version 7 or higher should be able to handle smtp functions. I just mention zimbra since thats what I am familiar with. It was over two years ago, sorry for the confusion